# TSQL Remove duplicated rows on some column only

Tags: sql, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL - How can I remove duplicate rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/sql-how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)

Example this is my table:

SiteKey, Name, City

The SiteKey is auto increament, Name is different , but some times 2 Sitekey will have same City.

Example:

```
1, A , CityA
2, B,  CityB
3, C,  CityA
4, D,  CityF
```

so I need to remove rows 3, and keep rows 1,2,4 only.

its on SQL 2005 and up.

thanks your help.

Comment: Here's a link to a question which answers yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/sql-how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here are 2 ways you can do it.

```
DELETE t
FROM 
<table> t
WHERE EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 FROM <table> 
    WHERE t.SiteKey > SiteKey AND t.City = City)


DELETE t
FROM 
<table> t
INNER JOIN <table> t2
ON  t.City = t2.City
AND t.SiteKey > SiteKey
```

Answer (score 4):

This is standard SQL

```
DELETE
   mytable
WHERE
    SiteKey NOT IN 
    (
    SELECT
       MIN(SiteKey)
    FROM
       Mytable
    GROUP BY
       City
    ) --Don't need 'KeepMe'
```

Then, add a unique constraint

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable WITH CHECK ADD
   CONSTRAINT UQ_MyTable_City UNIQUE (City)
```

Comment: The standard SQL is not work for me on SQL 2005 Query.

Comment: @Ken Le: "Not work"? How doesn't it work...

Comment: nvm , but I tried use LEFT OUTER Join and remove column have null, its work... Thanks your help tpp, gbn. Have a nice day.

Comment: @gbn -- It didn't work because you named your subquery in the WHERE -- just remove the 'KeepMe' and it works fine.  Otherwise, nice solution, and +1 anyway for the unique constraint :-)